Flutter int reverting to previous value after updating value in SQFLite
I have an int putOffCount which should be set to 19 on button press. In reality the int is set to 19 momentarilly before returning to 0. I am working in Flutter with sqflite as a local database.
Button widget:
                                TextButton(
                                  child: Text("Change"),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    entry.putOffCount = 19;
                                    await _databaseService.updateMemo(entry);
                                    setState(() {});
                                  },
                                ),

updateMemo method:
  Future<void> updateMemo(Memo memo) async {
    final db = await _databaseService.database;
    await db
        .update('memos', memo.toMap(), where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [memo.id]);
  }

Memo class:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Memo {
  int? id;
  String title;
  String description;
  DateTime? createdDate;
  DateTime? targetDate;
  int? putOffCount;

  Memo({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    this.createdDate,
    this.targetDate,
    this.putOffCount,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    String setCreatedDate = '';
    String setTargetDate = '';

    if (createdDate == null) {
      String formatted =
          DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(DateTime.now());
      setCreatedDate = formatted;
    } else {
      setCreatedDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(createdDate!);
    }

    if (targetDate == null) {
      String formatted = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
          .format(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: 1)));
      setTargetDate = formatted;
    } else {
      setTargetDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(targetDate!);
    }

    int setCount;
    if (putOffCount == null) {
      setCount = 40;
    } else {
      setCount = putOffCount ?? 50;
    }
    return {
      'title': title,
      'description': description,
      'createdDate': setCreatedDate,
      'targetDate': setTargetDate,
      'putOffCount': setCount,
    };
  }

  factory Memo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    DateTime tempTargetDate;
    if (map['targetDate'] != null) {
      tempTargetDate = DateTime.parse(map['targetDate']);
    } else {
      tempTargetDate = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: 1));
    }
    return Memo(
      id: map['id']?.toInt() ?? 0,
      title: map['title'] ?? '',
      description: map['description'] ?? '',
      createdDate: DateTime.parse(map['createdDate']),
      targetDate: tempTargetDate,
      putOffCount: map['putOffCount'] ?? 30,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Memo.fromJson(String source) => Memo.fromMap(json.decode(source));

  // Implement toString to make it easier to see information about
  // each dog when using the print statement.
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Memo(id: $id, title: $title, description: $description, createdDate: $createdDate,targetDate: $targetDate, putOffCount: $putOffCount)';
  }
}


I tried variations of *await * and .then() methods with no success. Any help would be very appreciated.

Maybe you could clarify in your post what exactly you mean by: In reality the int is set to 19 momentarily before returning to 0? Are you building a widget that is displaying the updated instance of Memo?

The memos are pulled from a SQFlite local database and displayed in a listview. Initially the putItOff int has 0 displayed then when I press the change button 19 is momentarilly displayed before 0 being once again displayed.

The problem seems be with the StatefulWidget where you are displaying, I am assuming, a list of memos.
